# How to merge two array data and make one array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I tried to merge two array and create a single array so i can submit these data to backend,but every time i do so the merged array shows empty array.How can i solve this issue,since i am new on react js please provide me the solution.

Following below are my code:

```
 <button type="submit" onSubmit={this.salGen}>Generate Salary</button>
```

from this function i tried to submit the data.

```
  salGen = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { finalClassDetails } = this.state;
    const { selectedEmployee } = this.state.data;
    this.setState({
        generateSalary: [...finalClassDetails, ...selectedEmployee]
    })
}
```

this is the function i created to merge two arrays.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        salaryDetails: [],
        classDetails: [],
        data: {
            selectedEmployee: [
            ],
            year: '',
            month: '',
        },
        finalClassDetails: [],
        isgeneratingSalary: false,
        dadays: '',
        finalDA: '',
        generateSalary: []
    }
}
```

This is my state.

These are the two arrays i want to merge and create a single array named:generateSalary[]
[[image: selectedEmployee[]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIN9i.png)

[image: finalclassDetails[]

Comment: it looks that you merge the arrays properly, where do you check `generateSalary` ?

Comment: When you're dealing with states, you don't ever alter the original array. You create a copy of it. If you're just merging the two with no sorting/etc you can do `const newArr = [...arr1, ...arr2]`

Comment: you did everthing correctly, make a callback funciton on the state to check your updated data

Comment: i got the output by calling call back function,thankyou...